# How to show more/all of the info in the function parameter tooltip?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

When you start filling out function parameters, a tooltip pops up showing the list of parameters the function is expecting, and optionally some description underneath if one is provided by adding comments above the function definition.

```
/** 
*   Some optional text with info about the function, etc.
*/
myFunction(param1, param2... ){};
```

My problem is that the description bit of the function I'm using doesn't fit inside the tooltip box.

http://oi62.tinypic.com/212a3dk.jpg
The pic shows what I mean.

It gets down to the bottom of the tooltip box and keeps going, beyond the visible rectangle boundaries. There are several more lines below where it cuts off at that I would like to be able to see.

How do I view the rest of the description inside the tooltip?

I was expecting some kind of scroll bar or something to resize the tooltip rectangle with.

Also is there a way to have the tooltip box always open, like have it as a dockable window that will show the parameter info of whatever I'm currently mousing over?

Comment: I have same problem!

Comment: http://support.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W404 Use this!

Comment: No  forget previous one, use this https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/ :)